# What configuration to use to prevent anyone from accessing the Prometheus web interface

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus

I'm experimenting with Prometheus to monitor and visualize the performance of several Java services. Works great and with Grafana the visual overview is very impressive.

But I don't seem to find how you can configure Prometheus itself to prevent its web interface to be publicly available. Grafana does this out of the box...

If I want to run everything on a cloud server, it would be great if I could check the /graph and /targets URL for instance, to check if everything is working OK before creating dashboards in Grafana.

Anyone who can point me to the right documentation?
I went through this page, but didn't find exactly what I was looking for:
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/

For info, this is my docker compose:

```
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.21.0
    container_name: prometheus
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/alerts.yml:/etc/prometheus/alerts.yml
      - ./prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      - /var/app/prometheus-data:/prometheus
    command: --web.enable-lifecycle --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    restart: unless-stopped

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: grafana
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./grafana/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
      - /var/app/grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana
      - /var/app/grafana/provisioning:/etc/grafana/provisioning
    environment:
      - GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=grafana-clock-panel
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=changeme
    restart: unless-stopped
```

And my prometheus.yml file:

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  - "/etc/prometheus/alerts.yml"

# Scrape configurations
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any time series scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ '127.0.0.1:9090' ]
  - job_name: 'java-service-1'
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prometheus doesn't implement it's own authentication|authorization.

Your best approach is to secure access to all host(s) running all software and, in this case, to the hosts running these Docker containers and all targets that you scrape etc.

All cloud providers provide ways by which you may limit access to the resources you create with their platforms. You'll want to become familiar with your preferred platforms' mechanisms and you should establish confidence, in part, by proving to yourself that you're able to restrict access to your services when you deploy then to these platforms.

Perhaps start with a simple test web site, secure it, then test that it is secure. Once you're confident in doing this, deploy your Prometheus services.

See this document on Prometheus [security](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/security/)

Comment: Thanks DazWilkin for the info, the monitored services and their APIs are protected so that's OK. But indeed will need to restrict access to the Prometheus web interface on the platform side if it is not possible in Prometheus itself.